# Convert DateTime in concatenate select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert `Date` column in this select but it returns an error

```
SELECT 
   isnull(CAST([Barcode] AS VARCHAR), '') + ';' + 
   isnull(CAST([DocumentTypeID] AS VARCHAR), '') + ';' +  
   isnull(CAST([FlowStatusId] AS VARCHAR), '') + ';' + 
   isnull(CAST([DocumentStatusId] AS VARCHAR), '')  + ';' + 
   isnull(CAST([DATE] AS VARCHAR), '') AS 'DATE' 
FROM 
   dbo.PSDOC 
WHERE  
   DATEPART(m, Data) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

The error is:

> Invalid column name 'DATE'. Severity 16

Comment: Do you have a column `DATE` in `PSDOC`?

Comment: yes I do I forget to put -->  AS 'DATE' but it doesn't work

Comment: This part `CAST([DATE] AS VARCHAR)` is using a column `DATE` in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error said. you do not have a column named "date"

Seems your column name is DatA not date. As far as i can read in the where clause:

Change:

```
isnull(CAST([DATE] AS VARCHAR), '') AS 'DATE' FROM dbo.PSDOC
```

to

```
isnull(CAST([DATA] AS VARCHAR), '') AS 'DATE' FROM dbo.PSDOC
```

Or even better use convert

```
isnull(CONVERT(varchar(20), [DATA], <format>), '') AS 'DATE' FROM dbo.PSDOC
```

Find the format you need here [Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CAST_TSQL%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true)

Unless you want prior month for all years, you should consider changing the where clause

```
WHERE  DATEPART(m, Data) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

Change to

```
WHERE data >=dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0) 
  and data < dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp), 0)
```

Comment: WHERE data >=dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0) 

 I think that spose to return the las day in the month ???? --> and data < dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, current_timestamp)-1, 0)